# Applying VBA Macro to one column, specific code

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with the following code from https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/

I want to change it so that Excel only runs Column A (1). What edit(s) do I need to make?

The macro is to allow multiple selections from a data validation dropdown. I'm getting an error, I think because I have other data validations running on the same sheet, which is formatted as a table.

Data Validation Error is Field Type Information / A2 / Restriction: Value must match one of the listed items

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
' To make mutliple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String

On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Target.Column = 1` already restricts it to ColA.  If you're getting an error it's useful to describe what the error is and where and when it occurs.

Comment: What is the error and on which line? I suspect `Target` is a multi-cell rangel when you get the error, because the code does not at all handle multi-cell range change events.

Comment: Field Type Information / A2 / Restriction: Value must match one of the listed items... so error is data validation, not VBA @TimWilliams

Comment: Field Type Information / A2 / Restriction: Value must match one of the listed items... so error is data validation, not VBA @ScottHoltzman

Comment: I've applied the Data Validation with the multi-select code to many cells on a single worksheet. The multi-select is only allowed in Column A -- so the code is working for me. I have not been able to reproduce the error. I've even created a table with some and with all columns in the table using the same and different validation lists. Still not getting the same (or any) error. There's something else going on...

Answer (score 1):

You check that Target starts in Column A. But it could extend to multiple columns, e.g. A1:C10. To refer to just the first column, you could use Target.Columns(1), but others point out that the code might misbehave if you select more than one cell. So, I suggest either

A) After *If Target.Column = 1 Then*, put a line *Set Target = Target.Cells(1)*
Or
B) Modify *If Target.Column = 1 Then* to *If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then*

Option A performs your action for just the first cell in the Target range. Option B causes your code to trigger only if a single cell is being edited. A third option is to loop through all cells in Target.